# int value converted to Integer Wrapper class object with System.out.println?

Tags: java

This more of a clarity than a doubt. In the following :

```
int a = 10;
System.out.println(a);
```

What I conclude is that variable 'a' of the primitive type `int` is first converted to the `Integer` Wrapper class object and then `toString` method is invoked for that `Integer` object which returns the integer value in String form to the `println` method. Is my understanding correct? If not what is the correct explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong. It can handle `int`, see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-int-)<sup>*</sup>:

```
public void println(int x)
```

<sup>* Always :)</sup>

Comment: Yup..thats correct explanation. I got confused with the overloaded method "public void println(Object x)" in which case the default toString is invoked ..

Comment: @user2580086 When you want to print your own object, then you override `toString` exactly because of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the type of `System.out`, you'll see it's a `PrintStream`.  [Read the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Quote:

```
public void println(int x)

Prints an integer and then terminate the line. This method behaves 
as though it invokes print(int) and then println().

Parameters:
    x - The int to be printed.
```

So, no, no conversion to `Integer` is done.  The `int` matches the signature of the above method exactly, so that method is called.  What happens internally is unspecified, but it probably calls `Integer.toString()` directly, with out a conversion to `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

No i think it's not the way you explained.

System.out is a static reference of PrintStream class (present in java.io package) which has methods to print primitives directly!!!

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, it actually uses the `String.valueOf(int)` method.

This is the source code, from `PrintStream`

```
/**
 * Prints the string representation of the int {@code i} followed by a newline.
 */
public void println(int i) {
    println(String.valueOf(i));
}
```